Apex Link Builder target (equals vs contains)
I have a link from a chart to an Interactive grid that applies a basic filter and I would like to apply a contains vs equals operator.



Check out the documentation regarding linking to IG
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.1/htmdb/linking-to-interactive-grid-reports.html#GUID-96314AB9-E018-4253-8C4B-3E053FE6134C
In your case, I believe the parameter name would become:
IGC_LOCATION_NAME

